# Universal quantification and set notation

Tags: logic, summation

I'm working on a series that describes part of an algorithm. I must define a variable `f` which should assume two different possible values `"black"` and `"white"` for different iterations of my algorithm. However, `"black"` and `"white"` are not numeric values, so I don't know how to do that in a proper way ...

Here is my try:
[image]

I don't know if it's fine to integrates a quantifier with a set... How can I say that `f` assumes "black" for the first iteration and "white" for the second iteration?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're trying to do here. What algorithm? What is $T_p?$ Are you programming? (If not, who cares... it's just some two-element set. If so, code it as zero/one or use something like an enum type). When you say '$\forall f\in\{b,w\}$" you are stating something is true for both values of $f.$ You can *check* this statement by iterating checking first black and then white.

Comment: I guess I should add that it can be expressed as a conjunction over $f.$ Can write it as $\bigwedge_{f\in\{"black","white"\}}$ on the outside

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try to clear this: yes, I have a program that performs this logic summation. In this program, the first iteration uses f = black, while the second (last) iteration assumes f = white. It's all working fine, but I have to write it into a scientifical paper, so I have to be formal. If, lets say, f could assume natural number values (like 0 and 1), I can simply add a conjunction for f iterating from 0 to 1 (like I did for i), but f isn't a number, so I don't know how to write this...

Comment: what's wrong with my suggestion $ \bigwedge_{f\in \{"black", "white"\}}$? (Also you could just code black and white as zero and one).

Comment: I don't know, perhaps it is right. I don't have to iterate f in a logic summation? Like I did for i, j, k... Do you have any material to recommend me in order to guide me towards your answer? Thanks for the reply :) (edit: it's not a code problem, it's a representation/formalism problem. To keep it simple in the paper, I need to write the meaning of the values of f, which is black and white.)

Comment: Well I assumed the $\forall f\in\{b,w\}$ meant the whole thing needed to hold in both of two separate cases, in which case it would be represented as a conjunction over the two cases for $f.$ No material in particular... I would just consult papers in your field for what the common  conventions are.

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant... What I'm trying to say with the expression is something like "for f = white and f = black". When I write 
f ∈ {"black", "white"} I'm not assuming that f is black for iteration 1 and white for iteration two, right? To be more clear, If f can assume 0 and 1, I'll write ⋀(f = 0 to 1), like I did for variable i, for instance (iterating from 0 to P). However, as f can't assume a numeric value, I don't know how to force the iteration for "white" and "black". Am I right or your notation is correct and I'm not comprehending it well? Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Yeah, but my second point is why can't 'black' be $0$ and 'white by $1$? $f$ can assume a numeric value by coding it as one.... As to my first suggestion, I don't know what you mean by 'force the iteration'. But generally speaking, the notation $\bigwedge_{f\in\{"black", "white"\}}T(f)$ would be regarded as equivalent to $T("black")\land T("white").$

Comment: Part of the problem I think is that (at least in normal mathematical logic), the semantics of $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n f(i)$ is not iterating over anything. It is saying that $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ and ... are all true. There is no imperative sense like you have in a for loop, and in particular, the "evaluation" of $f(1),$ etc have no side effects and thus $\bigwedge$ is fully commutative. In my experience, when people are writing down an procedural algorithm, they use pseudocode and not logical notation.